# On a RHEL workin as ansible controller getting error running playbook

Tags: ansible-playbook

I have a playbook that runs with no errors in my local tests VM (CentOS7)
but when I run this same playbook on the prod servers (RHEL7).

I run below command

```
sudo ansible-playbook passwords.yml -e
```

and I keep getting the below error:

```
'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' -i irm-inventory -bK
 BECOME password: 
PLAY [Adjust password settings] ******************************************************************************************************************
 TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************
 fatal: [SERVERNAME]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr":
"Shared connection to SERVER_IP closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\n",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc":
1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}
**************************************************************************************************************************************
SERVERNAME                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What are possible causes for this issue?
I already tried with python2 and python3

Comment: Make sure you are on Ansible 2.9, upgrade if you are not, and then remove the explicit setting for the Python interpreter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, in this controller machine I do have ansible 2.8.17. A particularity is that if I try to run ansible without sudo I get an error:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.1.2.dist-info/METADATA'

Comment: OK, so update to 2.9: `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-ansible-2.9-rpms`, or better, use `rhel-7-server-ansible-2-rpms` so you will always be on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You call `ansible-playbook` with the `-bK` parameters: ask for privilege escalation password & run operations with become. This is usually fine, but might cause the problem.

I suggest to try without `-bK` first. If it works then your playbook doesn't need the `become`. If it dies with a task-specific error, then attempt a different [`become_method`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/become.html#directives):

> (at play or task level) overrides the default method set in
> ansible.cfg, set to sudo/su/pbrun/pfexec/doas/dzdo/ksu